python concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor causes BrokenProcessPool error when run in a Visual Studio Code notebook with Windows 10
The example code in the official doc of concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() :
import concurrent.futures
import math

PRIMES = [
    112272535095293,
    112582705942171,
    112272535095293,
    115280095190773,
    115797848077099,
    1099726899285419]

def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    sqrt_n = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
    for i in range(3, sqrt_n + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for number, prime in zip(PRIMES, executor.map(is_prime, PRIMES)):
            print('%d is prime: %s' % (number, prime))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

runs without any issues in a jupyter notebook in a ubuntu system, but fails with a "BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending." error in a jupyter notebook in Visual Studio Code in a Windows 10 system.
"Python 3.10.10 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Mar 21 2023, 18:39:17) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32"
I have consulted several posts that discuss this.
So yes, I know from this post and from my own tests that I can put the code in a .py script and call it from the notebook. That works.
And yes, I know (vaguely) that Windows behaves differently from other systems in creating processes, threads, etc.; this post briefly mentions it; but there does not appear to be a conclusion/solution.
So the point remains: given that it's claimed that this code should work in Windows, is there anything one can do to be able to run the code as per official documentation, in a jupyter notebook, in Visual Studio Code, in Windows 10?
Using a separate .py script has many inconveniences vs running the code in a notebook cell.
It just seems bizarre to me that official documentation should have code that clearly does not work in a major operating system, forcing every single person who encounters this error to go looking for workarounds and finding N different and quite inconvenient solutions. Unless there is something wrong with my python installation or settings, but most other code works fine, so...
BTW, for the record, I did also try some of the solutions that recommended to use multiprocessing Pool and similar; that resulted in the notebook cell freezing forever.

EDIT after a lot of further browsing, I found a possible solution that still allows to run the multiprocessing part in a notebook, only moving the worker function to a .py
https://medium.com/@grvsinghal/speed-up-your-python-code-using-multiprocessing-on-windows-and-jupyter-or-ipython-2714b49d6fac
The example shown in the above post works in Visual Studio Code.
I imagine that for the example in the concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() one would have to move the definition of is_prime to a .py and import it; not sure about the with part. To be tried.

EDIT 2
Yes, it works.  See my answer below.

The official documentation does not attempt to account for use of the code in a "notebook" environment. If it runs correctly as a py script (command line) in a Windows environment then you have to wonder what Jupyter is doing to mess things up. This is not a Python issue per se

And I am indeed wondering that.
However, what about the 'print' statement in the code? You know that nothing gets printed if I simply run the py script, so... If they were not planning for interactivity, why put a print statement that goes nowhere? Also, suppose I want to use the output of the executor.map, which can be a list. How do I do that if I cannot run the code in a notebook cell?

VSCode  is only tool to write code, when code is ready then don't use VSCode but run it directly in console.

if code works in console but has problem in VSCode then problems makes VSCode and you could send this problem to authors of VSCode

It does not work in a jupyter notebook started from a miniconda prompt either. Who would I write to for that?

Oh and BTW, just tried it directly at what I think you mean by 'console': I started the miniconda3 prompt, typed 'python', ran the official code example --> exactly the same error, no VSC, no jupyter involved, so.... Otherwise please suggest where I should try the code. Not as a .py script, as that is exactly my point.

@user6376297  Let's say the code shown in the question is wholly contained within a file called foo.py. Then, from a command prompt you run python3 foo.py what happens? If it works (and it certainly should) then you have to find out how miniconda3, VSCode and/or Jupyter are influencing the runtime behaviour.

@SIGHUP : it works (except that I must do python foo.py, not python3, but OK. It outputs the same stuff that I see when I run this in a jupyter notebook in ubuntu. And yes, I agree that the problem is to "find out how miniconda3, VSCode and/or Jupyter are influencing the runtime behaviour". I was just hoping that the experts here would be able to suggest how to find that out, or better, how to resolve the issue. I don't see the point of being defensive about stuff; if it does not work, it does not work; the end user is not always an IT engineer, and these issues are real and blocking.

Oh and BTW, regarding the above statement by @furas "VSCode is only tool to write code, when code is ready then don't use VSCode but run it directly in console." . I would change 'write' to 'write AND test' code, so if I am unable to test code in a live interactive notebook, that sort of defeats the object, doesn't it? Again, there is no blame to assign here, nobody is saying that anything is bad or wrong; I hope it's clear that I am just trying to resolve a practical problem with code that is otherwise very useful and powerful.

As per edit in my OP, and as explained in:
https://medium.com/@grvsinghal/speed-up-your-python-code-using-multiprocessing-on-windows-and-jupyter-or-ipython-2714b49d6fac
a solution is to move only the 'worker' function in a separate .py, after which the multiprocessing code can be run from a notebook in the environment I described.
So the code in the official documentation will run in Visual Studio Code, Windows 10, provided that:
1.this block of code:
import math

def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    sqrt_n = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
    for i in range(3, sqrt_n + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

is saved in a worker_function_definition.py file in a directory that is found by sys.path, and replaced by:
import worker_function_definition

2.this piece of code:
executor.map(is_prime, PRIMES)

is replaced by:
executor.map(worker_function_definition.is_prime, PRIMES)

I hope that by posting this here I will spare other users some pain.
The guy who posted that solution summed the situation up very well (see where he writes 'Have you ever tried...'). Clearly not just me then.
Perhaps one day someone will take pity on us poor Windows users, and just mention this small but oh so important detail in the official documentation.
